# Model objects versions in Django

Tags: django, version, models

I'm building an e-commerce website.
I have a Product and Order models.
It's possible that a customer order a product and then the admin change its price
or other fields before the customer actually get it.

A possible solution is to add a 'version' field to the Product model.
When the admin update a product field I'll add a timestamp and create a new object
instead of updating the old one.
An Order will have a reference to a specific product version.

Does this make sense?
Will overriding the Product Save method be sufficient to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way:

Make a duplicate of the relevant product columns in the order table.

When you add a product to the order, *copy* everything from Product to Order (include a FK too if you want). That way the admin can do whatever they want (change product name/price/category/etc.), but the product price / name / etc. will always remain the same.

You could do a version column in product as you suggested, but that's a lot more complicated.

Comment: Copying the product fields to the order is a good idea.
The only problem is that different type of products have different fields.
Maybe Ill just copy everything to a text field and only the fields common to all the product types to separate fields.
Thanks